# Number of items in a combobox in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, count

HI,
How do i retreive the total number of items (count) of a combo box in Flex?

Answer (score 2):

random idea for you:

```
var dp : Object = combobox.dataProvider ;
if(dp is Array)
{
    //do something cool
}
else if(dp is ArrayCollection){
    //do something equally as cool
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

I've confirmed that this will work:

```
(comboBox.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).length
```

Comment: You're assuming that the dataProvider is an ArrayCollection. It could also be an Array. See jeremy.mooer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
combobox.collection.length
```

where `combobox` is the combobox you are using

I'm not sure this will work though. You may need to subclass the control because collection is a protected member :(

Answer (score -1):

The dataprovider of combobox is an arraycollection.  You can use the length property to count the number.

Comment: Wrong! It's a write-only property.

Comment: Maybe, it is not clear.  My meaning is the length property of the arraycollection.

Comment: `dataprovider` is a write-only property.

Comment: I think his point is that he would have put the arraycollection in there, so he could go back to the original reference and take its length.

Comment: Tim, yes, that is my meaning.